# Conditional AFTER UPDATE Trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I am trying my hand at writing triggers and want to have an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger such that:

1. Only when all "**TypeA**" records are updated (through UI) to "**Issued**", -->for each unique OrderID:

   Status of Master1 (for same OrderID) should be updated to '**TypeA 
   Issued**'.

   Similarly, when all TypeB issued in Details1,
    Master1.Status should be '**TypeB Issued**' and so on for other types

   Since the number of rows for each Type (in Details1) can vary, I am using the count value of Not Issued as a condition, since the trigger needs to fire only when the count becomes 0
2. Master2.Status is to be updated to TypeA Issued only for all TypeA status change (to Issued) in Details1 table.

I tried the this trigger but its updating Master1 even if the value of Status in Details1 is set to Not Issued. Also, where and how should I include Master2 update or should I write another trigger specifically for Master2 update

```
CREATE TRIGGER Master1_TypeAIssued_StatusUpdate
ON Details1
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT COUNT(Details1.Status)
          FROM Details1
          INNER JOIN Master1 ON Details1.OrderID = dbo.Master1.OrderID
          WHERE Details1.Status = 'Not Issued' AND
          Details1.Type = 'TypeA') = 0
      BEGIN
          RETURN
      END
  UPDATE Master1 SET Master1.Status = 'TypeA Issued'
END
```

```
OrderID     Type        Status
W1          TypeA       Not Issued
W1          TypeA       Not Issued
W1          TypeA       Not Issued
W1          TypeB       Not Issued
W1          TypeB       Not Issued
W1          TypeC       Not Issued
W2          TypeA       Not Issued
W2          TypeA       Not Issued
W2          TypeB       Not Issued

Master1 Table
OrderID     Status
W1          Pending
W2          Pending

Master2 Table
OrderID     Status
W1          Pending
W2          Pending
```

Comment: You shouldn't get any answers with those tags. This has nothing to do with vb.net or n-tier architecture. I would correct them for you but you didn't mention which database you are using.

Comment: I have retagged it based on the problem statement

Comment: @Mary, Sorry about that. Was trying to add MS SQL Server as a tag.

Answer (score 0):

try changing your condition to below:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(Details1.Status)
          FROM Details1
          INNER JOIN Master1 ON Details1.OrderID = dbo.Master1.OrderID
          WHERE Details1.Status = 'Not Issued' AND
          Details1.Type = 'TypeA' 
           AND Details1.OrderId IN (Select OrderId from Inserted)) > 0
      BEGIN
          RETURN
      END
```

This is because you should not update when there are records which have status "not Issues"

Comment: Thanks. So the RETURN is executed if the condition is true. Is that how I should interpret? How should I update Master2?

Comment: yes that is how you should interpret.you need to write another conditional check in the same trigger to update master 2

Comment: @chlorinelemon, please mark this as an answer if the solution resolved your issue.Thanks

Comment: FYI,Inserted would have the records which are updated